# How do I prevent someone from reading my .htaccess file?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I added a .htaccess file to a folder to make it password protected. I would like to prevent all users from being able to read that .htaccess file, because it reveals the location of my .htpasswd (I don't have permissions on this server to put this file outside of the html tree).

I tried the suggestions at http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess8.shtml, but I can still read my .htaccess on a web browser. Here is my .htaccess:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/www/users/mylogin/HTML/some_hidden_dir/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "I don't have permissions on this server to put this file outside of the html tree" - you need to find yourself a less incompetent service provider :-)

Comment: It's my university, students can only put files under their personal home page folder...

Comment: Most normal configurations prevent files starting with a `.` from being read at all via HTTP. Why did they break this?

Answer (score 8):

I've always used this method in my main root HTACCESS file and it works like a charm:

```
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 satisfy all
</Files>
```

More info on this method from one of my bookmarks:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/05/20/improve-site-security-by-protecting-htaccess-files/

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the reply, but it doesn't work for me, I can still read the .htaccess file. I'm starting to suspect it's the web server that's misconfigured...

Comment: Where are you adding the snippet? make sure you're adding it to your **root** htaccess

Comment: I wasn't, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It does, since the root htaccess is the gateway to everything else. Try adding it and if it doesnt work will dig further in to see what is up.

Comment: Sorry my previous comment wasn't clear. I did try it, and it didn't help. Note that my root dir is not the domain.com root though, since I am restricted to a subfolder due to permissions. I tried a simple test to prevent access to a specific html file, and it did not work. Maybe it's just some weird server config?

Comment: Is the htaccess file working elsewhere? You can limit the use of th htaccess files to some dirs through the httpd.conf file, so make sure that the rules set there allows for for htaccess file usage on all dirs.